# How would i pull the correct value out of this php loop

Tags: php, loops

I have this PHP loop

```
$two_related_total = 0;
$three_related_total = 0;
$four_related_total = 0;
$five_related_total = 0;
$all_values = getRelatedProducts(91)
$arr = array(2, 3, 4, 5);
 foreach ($arr as $discount_quantity) {

  //do something in here here to get the discounted_price or the price
}
```

Here is the data in $getRelatedProducts. Basically i need to get the discounted total for each array

For example for the the value 2 I need to set the value of $two_related_total to be 729.0000 and so on...or if there is a better way to get the four values please help me out ....thanks in advance

```
[0] => Array
         (
             [product_id] => 180
             [price] => 749.0000
             [discounted_price] => 729.0000
             [cost] => 420.0000
             [quantity] => 2
         )

     [1] => Array
         (
             [product_id] => 180
             [price] => 749.0000
             [discounted_price] => 545.0000
             [cost] => 420.0000
             [quantity] => 3
         )

     [2] => Array
         (
             [product_id] => 180
             [price] => 749.0000
             [discounted_price] => 545.0000
             [cost] => 420.0000
             [quantity] => 4
         )

     [3] => Array
         (
             [product_id] => 180
             [price] => 749.0000
             [discounted_price] => 545.0000
             [cost] => 420.0000
             [quantity] => 5
         )

 )
```

Comment: Your question needs clarification - where are these numbers coming from?

Comment: your question is unclear. There is no 729.0000 value in the array and "discounted total" is not defined. Do you simply mean that you want to return `discounted_price`?

Comment: sorry updated my question...misstyped

Answer (score 1):

You could switch your related totals to an array:

```
$related_totals=array();
$all_values = getRelatedProducts(91)
$arr = array(2, 3, 4, 5);
foreach ($arr as $discount_quantity) {
   $related_totals[$discount_quantity]=$all_values[$discount_quantity]['price'];
   //do something in here here to get the discounted_price or the price
}
```

I'm not really understanding your question, as as others point out there's no 729 value, (although there are 749). But this gives you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I *THINK* this is what you want:

```
$discounts = array();

foreach($product_array as $key => $product) {
    $discounts[$key] = $product['discounted_price'];
}

echo $discounts[2]; // $545.00
```

Using an array to hold the discounts is far easier than trying to set up individual variables for each. Otherwise you'll eventually end up with `$five_hundred_bajillion_60_kajillion_and_3_discounted_total` as your products array grows.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want, but your question is really unclear.

```
$arr = array(2, 3, 4, 5);
$totals = array(2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0, 5=>0);
foreach ( $all_values as $product ){
  if (in_array($product['quantity'], $arr)) {
    $totals[$products['quantity']] += $product['discounted_price'];
  }
}
```

For the first two lines you could alternatively do:

```
$arr = range(2,5);
$totals = array_fill_keys($arr, 0);
```